# Will host see the initial CN record call, or the final A record?

Tags: dns, cname

CN record "CN" points to "A"

A record points to the IP of a server

Will the host know if a call was through "CN" or "A"? (i.e. when examining the request)

Or will the host assume all calls are being done through "A" no matter if the caller was via "CN" or via "A"

Comment: `CNAME` happens in the zone at the DNS level.  The server "endpoint" will only see the result of that CNAME transfer -- whatever A record that happens to be.  For example if you have a CNAME `sub_domainkey` with a value of `this.that.com` -- The DNS server will point you to the A record for `this.that.com` wherever that record lies, and your web server will never "see" that CNAME transfer.